# Dropdown content not showing on hover

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML

```
<header class='lap-12 row'>
    <div class="lap-2 center">
        <a href="#"><img src="logo-desktop.png" alt="logo-desktop"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="lap-8 center space-around">
        <a id='velos' href="#"><b>VELOS</b></a>
        <a href="#"><b>PRODUITS</b></a>
        <a href="#">LA MARQUE</a>
        <a href="#">CONSEILS</a>
        <a href="#">GARANTIE À VIE</a>
        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="lap-2">
    </div>
</header>
<div class="lap-12 dropdown-content">
    <div class="lap-12 dropdown-top">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="lap-12 dropdown-bottom">
        2
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my CSS :

```
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
}

#velos:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

The dropdown content is simply not showing on the hover of my 'velos' id..
The lap-* classes just give a width to my elements.

Comment: And it won't ... because `.dropdown-content` is not `#velos` child

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
#velos:hover .dropdown-content {}
```

Means:

When element with id `velos` is hovered, change the style of children having class `dropdown-content`

In your example, element with class `dropdown-content` doesn't have `#velos` as parent, so it won't be affected.

Try something like this:

```
<header class='lap-12 row'>
    <div class="lap-2 center">
        <a href="#"><img src="logo-desktop.png" alt="logo-desktop"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="lap-8 center space-around">
        <a id='velos' href="#"><b>VELOS</b>
          <div class="lap-12 dropdown-content">
              <div class="lap-12 dropdown-top">
                  1
              </div>
              <div class="lap-12 dropdown-bottom">
                  2
              </div>
          </div>        
        </a>
        <a href="#"><b>PRODUITS</b></a>
        <a href="#">LA MARQUE</a>
        <a href="#">CONSEILS</a>
        <a href="#">GARANTIE À VIE</a>
        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="lap-2">
    </div>
</header>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mgjLvLpa/2/)

I also added additional styles to dropdown, so there would be 1 common pixel with a link, and it would be usable as menu:

```
#velos:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  margin-top:-1px;
  padding-top:1px;
}
```

... otherwise it would dissapear after hovering it, as link would lose hover itself. At least in Chrome / Opera.

Answer (score 0):

> Your css is asking to set display: block; at .dropdown-content on hover as children of velos.

Obviously it is wrong and anyway it isn't the true way to do it, try this:

```js
    $("ul li").slideUp();
    $("label").mouseover(function () {
        $("ul li").slideToggle();
    });
```

```css
    ul {
        display: table;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

    ul li {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <label>One</label>
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
    </ul>
```